# No function exists to perform desired grouping and aggregation

Tags: sql, sql-server, group-by, ssms

I've run into a conundrum I was hoping someone could help me out with. I have a table with the following fields:

SalesPeriod, SalesRep, Contract, MarginPerProduct, ProductSold

I have to multiply the MarginPerProduct and ProductSold to get 'TotalMargin'

Here is an example of the code I am trying to make work:

```
SELECT                                                                                   
      SalesPeriod
     , SalesRep
     , Contract
     , MarginPerProduct*ProductSold as 'TotalMargin'

FROM
     tblSales

GROUP BY
     SalesPeriod
     , SalesRep
     , Contract
```

Of course, the multiplied columns are invalid because they are not part of the grouping, plus there's no aggregate function being used.

Is there a way to accomplish this type of grouping when using a non recognized aggregation?

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Why do you need to `GROUP BY`, can't you just do the multiplication for each row?

Comment: @HoneyBadger the reason I would group is because contracts have multiple rows, the grouping will bring them together. However, I believe the two who suggested to Sum() the multiplied rows gave me the solution. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Presumably, you want `sum()`:

```
SELECT SalesPeriod, SalesRep, Contract,
       SUM(MarginPerProduct * ProductSold) as TotalMargin
FROM tblSales
GROUP BYSalesPeriod, SalesRep, Contract;
```

Answer (score 2):

Why not just this

```
SELECT                                                                                   
      SalesPeriod
     , SalesRep
     , Contract
     , TotalMargin = MarginPerProduct*ProductSold 
FROM
     tblSales
```

If you want the `TotalMargin` to be summed up for each `SalesPeriod\SalesRep\Contract` then

```
SELECT                                                                                   
      SalesPeriod
     , SalesRep
     , Contract
     , TotalMargin = sum(MarginPerProduct*ProductSold) 
FROM
     tblSales
GROUP BY
     SalesPeriod
     , SalesRep
     , Contract
```

Comment: Pretty sure that is  operator (`=`) is mistyped here as it does not feel right in both SQL queries in the `TotalMargin = MarginPerProduct*ProductSold` and `TotalMargin = sum(MarginPerProduct*ProductSold) ` parts  .. ..

Comment: @RaymondNijland - There is nothing wrong with that syntax, Sql Server supports it, look it up. I prefer this way to assign alias names.

Comment: @RaymondNijland - Here is one good [article](https://sqlblog.org/2012/01/23/bad-habits-to-kick-using-as-instead-of-for-column-aliases) about it

Comment: Anyhow, i [tested](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=3bff1a0aeb749086cce64a5ac01c3f7e) with a open mind  it also does not seams to be working as a alias..  Unclear syntax to use which might mean different things, you claimed it worked like a alias, i see something else happen so i am forgetting this syntax directly.. *"Bad Habits to Kick : Using AS instead of = for column aliases"* I would that say instead that this is bad habit to drop instead of using `AS` to define aliases..

Comment: @RaymondNijland - I disagree, in sql server we use `=` for alias its more readable and clean. You may have different opinion but in Sql Server I'll suggest to use `=` than `AS`